# In TypeScript, how can I fix an error "property ____ is protected and only accessible within class ____"?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular 2 project and I am using a library called `ng2-bootstrap`.

I am using modals from this library, and there is a property called `_isShown` that I am checking in a function inside my class:

```
  proceed() {
    if (this.childModal._isShown) this.hideChildModal();  // error message here: "[ts] Property '_isShown' is protected and only accessible within class 'ModalDirective' and its subclasses."
    this.router.navigate(['signup-step-two']);
  }
```

It seems to work even though I get that error, but how can I fix that error correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `_isShown` is `protected` in `ModalDirective` source code. Check it out [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/components/modal/modal.component.ts#L59).

You can access the public value using `isShown()` function.

It is declared as `public` in the [source code](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/components/modal/modal.component.ts#L51).

```
  public get isShown(): boolean {
    return this._isShown;
  }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark as answer if it worked. :)